# React warnings are not showing up

Tags: google-chrome, reactjs, react-dom

i'm trying to recap some react basics. I wrote a tiny example, and expected to have a warning for not passing a key as an argument for each element for the map function.

JS:

```
var ing = [
    "1 cucumber",
    "2 tomatoes",
    "1/2 onion",
    "2 olive oil spoon"
];

var Div = React.createElement(
  "ul",
  null,
  ing.map( function(ing){ return  React.createElement("li", null, ing)})
);

ReactDOM.render(Div, document.getElementById("react-app"));
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react-dom.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="react-app"></div>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it does not show up (I'm using Chrome btw).

Comment: Make sure you're using the non minified (development version) of Rect. React strips out warnings and errors in the minified production version for performance reasons. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react.js

Comment: That solves everything. thanks!

Comment: No prob!!!!!!!!